# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, wikipedia-api

I am trying to add wikipedia API in django and process the wikipedia throung HTML input in view.py.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import wikipediaapi

from .forms import ContactForm, ColorfulContactForm

def _form_view(request, template_name='basic.html', form_class=ContactForm):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        mes = request.POST.get("message")
        search = mes.split(' ')
        query = search[2]
        #return HttpResponse(mes)
        mywiki(query)

        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
    else:
        form = form_class()
        search_id = request.POST.get('message', None)
    #
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})


def mywiki(query):
    wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.wikipedia('en')
    page_py = wiki.page(query)
    title = page_py.title
    return HttpResponse(title)        
#return HttpResponse(mes )
```

I get an error which reports:

```
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Anyone help me

Comment: when receiving exceptions, it could be more helpful to share the stack trace as well, so it's clear where the exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind error:


Correct format is `wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')`, not wikipediaapi.wikipedia('en') 
  
 Note that W in Wikipedia is in caps.

Also You should use

```
page_py = wiki_wiki.page(query)
```

instead of

```
page_py = wiki.page(query)
```

Since your object variable is wiki_wiki not wiki.

Comment: the algo is working fine, it works alone, but not in Django

Comment: What is the erorr you are getting after you updated the code with the edits I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: name 'wiki' is not defined

Comment: you should use `page_py = wiki_wiki.page(query)` . Not wiki.page(query). I mentioned this in answer.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you @SamiUllah

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the line

```
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.wikipedia('en')
```

according to Wikipedia API docs

```
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
```

`Wikipedia` starting with capital `W`, which is a class name is called to create the instance. What currently is being used is `wikipedia.wikipedia` which is a Python [module](https://github.com/martin-majlis/Wikipedia-API/blob/master/wikipediaapi/wikipedia.py), and as the exception hints, is not callable.